# Index page on Apache web server

Tags: apache, indexing

So I downloaded and installed Apache's web server on my PC (which runs Windows 7 Home Premium). 
I put the domain as the domain I registered (the-social-project.info) when installing
I configured the file to where my files will be. 
Do I just write an index.html file in the directory I configured it as? Because when I do, and I go on the-social-project.info, the page shows up as "Oops! Google Chrome could not find the-social-project.info".

What do I do?

Thank you for looking!

Comment: Is the request from the browser actually making it to the web server?  Check the server logs.  You registered the domain, but is the DNS set up?

Comment: ping your url and see if it is showing the correct ip. if it is, its a configuration issue and we can better try to help.

Comment: Where did you put the domain settings? in your vhosts file?

Comment: Do you have to set up the DNS manually?

Comment: @Amy, what do you mean with manually? You normally use a control panel at your domain provider's web site. You have to say *somewhere* that your domain points to your computer. Otherwise, how can the rest of the world know?

Answer (score 1):

Your WHOIS record shows that you've registered the domain just 24 hours before. (http://www.who.is/whois/the-social-project.info/)

Usually, newly created domains will take upto 48 or 72 hours to propagate through all the major DNS servers around the globe. So, you can wait for a day, and check it again.

If till then it's not accessible, its high time to contact your registrar.

Comment: So after that, when I post a file to where my files are pointed to, it'll show up on my website?